# Can I install "development-tools" offline? Or, how to make my CD the yum repository?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, development

I'm looking for the "development-tools" for Fedora, but I can't find information about how/where to download it to install offline (I have no internet connection in my Fedora).

**Attempt 1:** There's a hint [here](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showpost.php?p=1438977&postcount=7) about how to use the DVD as repository, but I don't have the `media.repo` in the root of my Fedora 15 DVD.. any idea where's it?

**Attempt 2:** I also found [this image](http://www.bitbenderforums.com/~grogan/fedora/05_installtype.jpg), in a page saying that I can choose during the installation to install the development-tools. But I just re-installed Fedora paying attention, and didn't saw that screen or that option..

**Attempt 3:** I found [this approach](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-setup-repo.html), but it requires to install the `createrepo`, and I can't install a thing here..

**Using Bakha Nurzhanov's approach:**

Mount your DVD media: mount -r /dev/cdrom /media/CentOS
Create file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo with the following content:

```
[c5-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

Use your DVD to install "Development Tools"

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c5-media groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

On this last step I got:

```
$ yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c5-media
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
You need to give some command
Usage: yum [options] COMMAND
```

I checked, really there's no repodata folder or repomd.xml file.. Here's the DVD tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── EFI
│   └── boot
│       ├── bootx64.conf
│       ├── bootx64.efi
│       ├── grub.conf
│       ├── initrd0.img
│       ├── isolinux.bin
│       ├── isolinux.cfg
│       ├── memtest
│       ├── splash.jpg
│       ├── splash.xpm.gz
│       ├── vesamenu.c32
│       └── vmlinuz0
├── GPL
├── isolinux
│   ├── boot.cat
│   ├── initrd0.img
│   ├── isolinux.bin
│   ├── isolinux.cfg
│   ├── memtest
│   ├── splash.jpg
│   ├── vesamenu.c32
│   └── vmlinuz0
└── LiveOS
    ├── livecd-iso-to-disk
    ├── osmin.img
    └── squashfs.img

4 directories, 23 files
```

Is my version of the DVD different of your? I downloaded the lastest from the site..

Comment: That DVD looks very odd... it is obviously the Live version. You probably need an install DVD. Or you may be able to mount one of those `.img` files. There should be a subdirectory somewhere `/CentOS/RPMS` or something similar.

Comment: @Aaron D. Marasco I'm having a hard time finding another img to install in the website, as far as I can see there's only one version for me, it's this Desktop 64bits version. Where can I find the "install DVD" you're talking about? (I used the version I downloaded as an install DVD to install my Fedora successfully)

Comment: Also, the `/CentOS" directory was created by me in my computer to mount the DVD, as @Bakha Nurzhanov told to. There's nothing on it but the tree shown above.

Comment: No, @Bakha Nurzhanov said to mount it in "`media`" - if it is the correct image, it will have a `/CentOS/` like I had said. The DVDs I have always used have the same file tree as http://centos.mirror.facebook.net/5/os/x86_64/ I still say you have a "Live" version, which is different.

Comment: Wait... do you want the Fedora tools? Why are we talking about CentOS ISOs then? A Fedora 15 should look roughly like this: http://fedora.mirror.facebook.net/linux/releases/15/Fedora/x86_64/os/

Comment: @Tom:  The install DVD images [can be downloaded here](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options#formats).  Select either the 32 or 64 bit ISO under *Fedora 15 DVD* depending on which version you have installed.

Comment: @Patches thanks I'm downloading to test. I wonder why the version found in the Fedora home page is different.. Even the other non-live version is different of this yours.. It caused days of trouble to me.. :( Thanks again for the link :)

Answer (score 3):

`development-tools` is a set of packages related development. You should mount your Fedora ISO or CD, run `system-config-packages` in a terminal, check the packages you wanted to install under `development-tools`, then apply your change.

Comment: Looks like there's no `system-config-packages` command.. When I press tab twice the options are: system-config-authentication  system-config-network-cmd
system-config-date            system-config-network-tui
system-config-firewall        system-config-printer
system-config-firewall-tui    system-config-printer-applet
system-config-keyboard        system-config-users
system-config-network

Answer (score 2):

- Mount your DVD media:

```
mount -r /dev/cdrom /media/CentOS
```

- Create file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo` with the following content:

```
[c5-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

- Use your DVD to install "Development Tools"

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c5-media groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Please, check my update explaining why this doesn't worked..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to connect to a package repository of some kind. You can set your package manager (in the case of Fedora it should be `yum`) to use your CD's as the repository. Usually configurations for this are in the default config file but not enabled. Look in `/etc/yum/repos.d` to see if you can find the name of the repository that is configured for your cd media.

Once your repo is configured as default or you know what yum command to run to have it enabled (`yum --enablerepo=cdrom_repo_name` or something like that) you should be able to install whatever tools you need. `yum install make autoconf gcc [...]`.

All that being said, the easiest way to do this is get the machine online. Temporarily add a network card if you have to, but do something to get it online, updated, and install the packages you need, then go back to fixing your other issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The wireless usb adapter is already a workaround for my wired network that is not working.. I no other option. I found details about how to use the cd as repository, but looks like it's not the same for Fedora 14 and 15, or a file is missing in my cd.. please, see my update.